# How manage raising events of UserControls with TestStack.White?

Tags: c#, wpf, white-framework, devexpress-wpf, teststack

I'm testing my wpf application and I need to verify if certain usercontrol events correctly raise or not like, for example, Loaded/Unloaded events.
I've already created my UserControl class (I'm using DevExpress WPF Controls) because I know that TestStack.White doesn't support natively third party controls, the code is this:

```
[ControlTypeMapping(CustomUIItemType.Custom, WindowsFramework.Wpf)]
    public class UserControl : CustomUIItem
    {
        public UserControl(
            AutomationElement automationElement, 
            ActionListener actionListener)
            : base(automationElement, actionListener)
        {            
        }

        protected UserControl()
        {            
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler Loaded;

        public event RoutedEventHandler Unloaded;
    }
```

but now I don't understand how I can verify events raising or not. Does anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution and could provide it?